# Prove the $\cos^n \phi$ and $\sin^n \phi$ property

Tags: trigonometry

Question :

> Prove that
>
> $$\cos^n{\phi}=\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}\left(\cos {n\phi} + n\cos {(n-2)\phi}
>  + \frac{n(n-1)}{2!}\cos{(n-4)\phi}+\cdots + R_n\right)$$
>
> Where
>
> $$R_n= \begin{cases}
>  &\frac{n!}{\left(\frac{(n-1)}{2}\right)!\left(\frac{n+1}{2}\right)!}\cos
> \phi\quad &\text{if $n$ is odd}\\ &\frac{n!}{2\left[\left(\frac n
>  2\right)!\right]^2}\quad &\text{if $n$ is even} \end{cases}$$
>
> And derive the similar result for $\sin^n \phi$

Well, i have two ideas about it:

First, i have to use power reducing formula.

Second, i have to use De Moivre's Theorem (But, i doubt it)

Please, which one of them will work? Or, maybe if you have a correct or better idea then tell me.

And what about $\sin^n \phi$ ?

Is the idea will be the same?

Thanks for all.

---

Edit :

What about i'm using the fact that

$$\cos^2 \phi=\frac{1+\cos {2\phi}}{2}$$

But my problem is the first term on that property, that is $1$, cz as we know, we don't see the term $1$ in that equation if we use binomial expansion. Or could it be vanished by another coefficients?

Comment: What is the '......' part of the series? Do we stop when the argument of cosine becomes 0 or 1?

Comment: I think, the $\cdots$ part is the $R_n$

Comment: Using the Binomial Theorem, we get $$ \begin{align} \cos^n(\phi) &=\frac1{2^n}\left(e^{i\phi}+e^{-i\phi}\right)^n\\ &=\frac1{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}e^{i(n-2k)\phi}\\ &=\frac1{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\cos((n-2k)\phi)\\ \end{align} $$

Comment: I think '......' is the continued part of the series. I'm asking, 'Do we decrement n by 2 forever (infinite series), or do we stop the series somewhere'?

Comment: @robjohn Actually it's a good answer. Why don't you put it in the "add an answer" section. Anyway, for even and odd case, should i generalize it from here?

Comment: @RyderRude because the term of power is $n$, then it will stop in $n$. Isn't it?

Comment: I got it. The combinatorial coefficient becomes zero ultimately. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the Binomial Theorem, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\cos^n(\phi)
&=\frac1{2^n}\left(e^{i\phi}+e^{-i\phi}\right)^n\tag1\\
&=\frac1{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}e^{i(n-2k)\phi}\tag2\\
&=\frac1{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}e^{i(2k-n)\phi}\tag3\\
&=\frac1{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\frac12\left[\binom{n}{k}e^{i(n-2k)\phi}+\binom{n}{k}e^{i(2k-n)\phi}\right]\tag4\\
&=\frac1{2^n}\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\cos((n-2k)\phi)\tag5
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: $\cos(\phi)=\frac12\left(e^{i\phi}+e^{-i\phi}\right)$
$(2)$: [Binomial Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem)
$(3)$: substitute $k\mapsto n-k$ and apply the symmetry of [Pascal's Triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle)
$(4)$: average $(2)$ and $(3)$
$(5)$: $\cos(\phi)=\frac12\left(e^{i\phi}+e^{-i\phi}\right)$

Using the evenness of $\cos(\phi)$, gives the formulation mentioned.

Comment: Ok, just one quick question. From second row to the third. It's from $e^{ix}=\cos{x} +i \sin{x}$ right? Why does $i\sin{x}$ vanished?

Comment: @user516076: there are several ways to look at this. If you add the sum and the sum with $n-k$ substituted for $k$ and divide by $2$, then use $\cos(x)=\frac{e^{ix}+e^{-ix}}2$, no $\sin(x)$ ever appears. Another way is to notice that $\sin(x)$ is odd and notice that the terms for $k$ and $n-2k$ cancel.

Comment: @robjohn I looked at it as, since the LHS $cos^n\phi$ is real, so the RHS must be real too. Hence the imaginary sin terms must cancel out. I guess this is wrong because the LHS can be complex for complex $\phi$.

Comment: I have expanded the answer to include the first of the two approaches I mentioned in my previous comment.